# How to log an error into a Table from SQLPLus

Tags: oracle10g, sqlplus

I am very new to Oracle so please base with me if this is covered else where.

I have a MS SQL box running Jobs calling batch files running scripts in SQLPLUS to ETL to an Oracle 10G database.

I have an intermittent issue with a script that is causing the ETL to fail which at the minute without error logging is something of an unknown. The current solution highlights the load failure based on rowcounts for before and after the script has finsihed.

I'd like to be able to insert any errors encoutered whilst running the offending script into an error log table on the same database receiving the data loads.

There's nothing too technical about the script, at a high level is performs the following steps all via SQL code and no procedural calls.

1. Updates a table with Date and current row counts
2. Pulls data from a remote source into a staging table
3. Merges the Staging table into an intermediate staging table
4. Performs some transformational actions
5. Merges the intermediate staging table into the final Fact table
6. Updates a table with new row counts

Please advise whether it is possible to pass error messages, codes, line number etc etc via SQLPLUS into a Database table? and if so the easiest method to achieve this.

A first few lines of the script are shown below to give a flavour

```
/*set echo off*/
set heading off
set feedback off
set sqlblanklines on

/* ID 1 BATCH START TIME */
INSERT INTO CITSDMI.CITSD_TIMETABLE_ORDERLINE TGT
(TGT.BATCH_START_TIME)
(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL);
COMMIT;

insert into CITSDMI.CITSD_TIMETABLE_ALL_LOADS
(LOAD_NAME, LOAD_CRITICALITY,LOAD_TYPE,BATCH_START_TIME)
values
('ORDERLINE','HIGH','SMART',(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL));
commit;

/* Clear the Staging Tables */

TRUNCATE TABLE STAGE_SMART_ORDERLINE;
Commit;

TRUNCATE TABLE TRANSF_FACT_ORDERLINE;
Commit;
```

and so it goes on with the rest of the steps.

Any assistant will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not fully understanding your requirement, a couple of pointers.

1. The WHENEVER command will help you control what sqlplus should do when an error occurs, e.g.

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK

INSERT ...

INSERT ...

This will cause sqlplus to exit with error status 1 if any of the following statements fail.

You can also have WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE ...

Since the WHENEVER ... EXIT FAILURE/SUCCESS controls the exit status, the calling script/program will know if it worked failed.

1. Logging

use SPOOL to spool the out to a file.

1. Logging to table.

Best way is to wrap your statements into PLSQL anonymous blocks and use exception hanlders to log errors.

So, putting the above together, using a UNIX shell as the invoker:

```
sqlplus -S /nolog <<EOF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE ROLLBACK
CONNECT ${USRPWD}
SPOOL ${SPLFILE}

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO the_table ( c1, c1 ) VALUES ( '${V1}', '${V2}' );
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      INSERT INTO the_error_tab ( name, errno, errm ) VALUES ( 'the_script', SQLCODE, SQLERRM );
      COMMIT;
END;
/

SPOOL OFF 
QUIT
EOF

   if [ ${?} -eq 0 ]
   then
      echo "Success!"
   else
      echo "Oh dear!! See ${SPLFILE}"
   fi
```